# Can jquery ajax be told only the form id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mootools

When I send ajax requests with jquery, I specify a `data` array, like

```
data: {param1: 'somevalue', param2: 'another value' }
```

I saw some old code written in MooTools 1.2 and it seems MooTools makes it possible to send the whole form as is, without the need to specify the fields one by one. You just give it the form id, in this case `theform`.

```
var theNewRequest = new Request.HTML({url:'ajaxpage.php'}).post($('theform'));
```

Is there something similar in jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the serialize function to send the serialized contents of the form.

```
$.post("ajaxpage.php", $("#theform").serialize());
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `$.post('somewhere',$('formid').serialize(), function(data){})`?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this script a couple weeks back to simplify AJAX form submission:

```
/**
 * 
 * Autesion King of Thebes
 * 
 * Also, a simple script by zzzzBov to automatically submit a form via AJAX
 */
(function($){
"use strict";
function autesion(options){
  var settings;
  settings = $.extend(true, {}, autesion.defaultSettings, options);
  this.submit(function(e){
    var $this, ajaxSettings, $form;

    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented())
    {
      $this = $(this);
      $form = $(e.target);
      ajaxSettings = $.extend({}, settings.ajaxSettings, {
        'data':$form.serialize(),
        'type':$form.attr('method') || 'GET',
        'url':$form.attr('action')
      });

      if (settings.useEvents)
      {
        ajaxSettings.beforeSend=function(j,s){
          $this.trigger(new $.Event('autesion.beforeSend', {jqXHR:j, settings:s}));
        };
        ajaxSettings.complete=function(j,t){
          $this.trigger(new $.Event('autesion.complete', {jqXHR:j, textStatus:t}));
        };
        ajaxSettings.error=function(j,t,e){
          $this.trigger(new $.Event('autesion.error', {jqXHR:j, textStatus:t, errorThrown:e}));
        };
        ajaxSettings.success=function(d,t,j){
          $this.trigger(new $.Event('autesion.success', {jqXHR:j, textStatus:t, ajaxData:d}));
        };
      }

      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax(ajaxSettings);
    }
  });

  if (settings.useEvents)
  {
    this.bind('autesion.beforeSend', settings.beforeSend)
      .bind('autesion.complete', settings.complete)
      .bind('autesion.error', settings.error)
      .bind('autesion.success', settings.success);
  }

  return this;
};
autesion.defaultSettings={
  'ajaxSettings':{},
  'beforeSend':$.noop,
  'complete':$.noop,
  'error':$.noop,
  'success':$.noop,
  'useEvents':true
};

$.fn.autesion = autesion;

}(jQuery));
```

I'm certain it can be significantly improved, but it should work as-is as long as you don't require file input support.

To use it, simply call:

```
$('form').autesion();
```

The short form is:

```
$form = $('form');
$form.ajax({
  'data': $form.serialize(),
  'type': $form.attr('method') || 'GET',
  'url': $form.attr('action')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form elements.

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/